# How can I detect if a player steps on a certain block in vanilla 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So say I want to make a portal, but want whoever steps in it to go to a specific location, without going to another dimension. How could I do that in vanilla Minecraft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select every player that stands on that specific block. For those players, you need to use a teleport command to teleport them to your desired location.

To select all the players you use `execute as @a`.
You also need to execute at the location of each player: `execute as @a at @s`.
Only if there's a specific block below the player: `execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ [Your block]`.
Finally, you need to teleport everyone who has this condition to your desired location. The final command looks like this:

```
execute as @a at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ [Your block] run teleport @s [your coordinates]
```

Obviously you replace [Your block] with the block of your choice and [your coordinates] with the coordinates of your choice, without the square brackets ofcourse.

Notice that this works regardless of the dimension. If somebody in the nether stands on this block, this person gets teleported to the specified coordinates in the nether for example.

If you only want to use this in one specific dimension, then you can select only those players that are in your desired dimension. You would replace `@a` with `@a[nbt={Dimension:0}]`, where 0 is the overworld, -1 is the nether and 1 is the end.

Comment: I think you can use `at @a` instead of `as @a at @s`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @FabianRöling If you use `at @a` instead of `as @a at @s`, then the command block will check from the position of each player and then try to teleport itself to the set coordinates. If that command is run in chat, then the player using the command would be teleported if any player stands on the specified block.